# C# process.start not working on iis

Tags: c#, .net, process, cmd

I'm trying to run an exe with parameters from a web application.

I'm using Process.start() but it does not seem to run on iis!

It works fine when running from iis express. I'm publishing the application to my local iis as a test but it does nothing.

I've tried setting the iis admin service to enable interactions with the desktop and ive told iis to connect as my user credentials and set the application pool to use the same user credentials but still nothing works!

is there anything else someone can advise to get this working!

Cheers.

**UPDATE**

I got iis to run the process by setting the application pool identity to local system and double checking the credentials for the site.

But as expected the applications do not interact with the desktop, so creating a file from command line is simple, but running an application with parameters do not have the application open.

At the moment iis admin service has interact with desktop checked and is using the local system account.

Comment: Do you get an error, or does it just appear to do nothing? If the latter, what are you doing to determine that it's not running? Keep in mind that IIS runs as a service, and services can't interact with the desktop, so your EXE won't be able to show any UI -- so if you're looking for a window, you won't see it.

Comment: Just so that we're clear - you do understand that if you do get this to work, the program you're launching will be running on the *server*, not the machine that is running the browser (when that is  a different machine)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I need it to run on the server when it is on another machine later, as strange as that is.

Comment: @JoeWhite It appears to be doing nothing, I don't know if it is not running or not appearing but I would expect to see something to appear in the processes. As a test i've tried to run the desired application and to try create a file using cmd.exe.

Comment: IISExpress is generally running as you, under Visual Studio. IIS will generally not be running as you. You need to check whether the process you are trying to start has all the permissions and accesses required to first find the program you want to run and then to run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this isn't really an answer but in the end I got process.start to work by setting the application pool identity to local system.

But as expected the commands do not interact with the desktop, but this was enough for what my application needs to do.

Sorry for the poor answer.